# How can I print 2 elements with putStr Haskell?

Tags: haskell, console-application

I'm new to Haskell and I am wondering how can I print the results of two functions in Haskell, something I would do in c++ like:

```
cout << f() << g();
```

Or in c#:

```
Console.WriteLine(f() + " " + g());
```

In Haskell I tried something like

```
main =
    --putStr ( show $ square 3 )
    putStr ( show $ fibSeries 12 ) 

square :: Int -> Int
square x = x * x

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

fibSeries :: Int -> [Int]
fibSeries x = map fib [0..x]
```

but I had to comment the first command because it has given me a compile-time error.

The error is:

```
src\Main.hs:21:5:
    Couldn't match expected type `(String -> IO ()) -> String -> t0'
                with actual type `IO ()'
    The function `putStr' is applied to three arguments,
    but its type `String -> IO ()' has only one
    In the expression:
      putStr (show $ square 3) putStr (show $ fibSeries 12)
    In an equation for `main':
        main = putStr (show $ square 3) putStr (show $ fibSeries 12)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like real code. What's the actual code and actual error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**tl;dr** You're so close!

```
main = do
    putStr ( show $ square 3 )
    putStr ( show $ fibSeries 12 )
```

Note that this won't put in any whitespace, you may wish to insert `putStr " "`.

---

Here's what's going on: Haskell's main part, the purely functional language, doesn't have any such thing as "order of computation / action". If you write two lines with statements like `print 5`, they're just parsed as one line, namely

```
print 5 print 5
```

which means the following: `print` is a function that takes the arguments `5`, `print`, and `5`, and returns the type of `main` (an `IO` action). So the type would need to be something like

```
type PrintType = Int -> PrintType -> Int -> IO()
```

which is of course nonsense. To tell Haskell you actually want to *sequence* a chain of actions (what you do all the time in imperative languages, but need much more seldom in functional programming), we have this nice `do` notation, which works a lot (but not always quite!) like you'd expect from an imperative standpoint.

To understand how that *really* works, you need to learn about monads. Those are explained in any decent Haskell tutorial. Read [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or something.

---

Further notes on your code: there's not much point in doing such a printing job sequentially, really. You can just produce a string with all the information you want, and then print that in one go:

```
main = putStrLn $ show (square 3) ++ " " ++ show (fibSeries 12)
```

or, if you're not so much interested in formatting but just in getting the information,

```
main = print ( square 3, fibSeries 12 )
```

which will result in the output `(9,[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144])`.

Comment: "You may wish to insert `putStr " "`", or you could replace `putStr` with `putStrLn` so that each output appears on a separate line.

Comment: Also, if you want a monad-free introduction to do notation you can read [this post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/01/introduction-to-haskell-io.html).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from do notation you can also use `sequence_` function to execute a series of independent `IO` actions:

```
main = sequence_ [putStr $ show $ square 3 ,
                  putStr $ show $ fibSeries 12]
```

Comment: Though I'd argue that `mapM_ (putStr . show) [square 3, fibSeries 12]` is more the point then. Also, you can omit the parens: `,` has even lower "precedence" than `$`. (And many Haskellers prefer to put it at the beginning of the next line, aligned with `[`.)